# Don't want window load if href has a #

Tags: javascript

I have this code to scroll my homepage after 4 seconds. However, I don't want to do this if the URL has a # in it (because I have another script to scroll to anchor).

What can I do to only load this script if there is not a # in the href?

```
$( window ).load(function() {
$('html,body').delay(4000) 
    .animate({
        'scrollTop': $('#services').offset().top -60
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutCirc');
```

});

Answer (score 3):

Check if `window.location.hash` is empty or not.

For example, if the url is like `http://example.com/#something`, the value of `window.location.hash` is `#something`.

Comment: So simple :-) It's working with this: if ( window.location.hash == "" ) {